# How to pass a html table cell content to img source with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html form that it's loaded with the information contained in a html table when a cell is clicked. The thing is that I'd like to load an image with the info contained in one of its column, in this case "PICTURE".

This columns just have the path where pictures are saved, so is there a way to get it and pass it to  or whaterver but the idea is to show the picture in this place.

Is it possible? Is there any other way?

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <img src="" id="photo">
    Name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>
    Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="nombre" id="lname"><br>
    Years:<br>
    <input type="number" name="edad" id="years"><br>
    Gender: 
    <input type="radio" name="g_m" id="g_m" value="m"> Mail
    <input type="radio" name="g_f" id="g_f" value="f"> Femail<br>
    Skill:<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="m1" id="m_html" value="html"> HTML
    <input type="checkbox" name="m2" id="m_python" value="python"> PYTHON<br><br>
    <input type="submit">
    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
<br>
<table id="list">
    <thead>
        <th>NAME</th>
        <th>LAST NAME</th>
        <th>YEARS</th>
        <th>GENDER</th>
        <th> SKILL </th>
        <th> PICTURE </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Carlos</td>
            <td>Smith</td>
            <td>28</td>
            <td>m</td>
            <td>html</td>
            <td>images/foto.jpg</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ana</td>
            <td>Snow</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>f</td>
            <td>python</td>
            <td>images/foto2.jpg</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is the JS:

```
var table = document.getElementById('list'),rIndex;
        for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++){
            table.rows[i].onclick = function(){
                rIndex = this.rowsIndex;
                for (var i = 0, len = document.getElementsByTagName("input").length; i < len; i++) {
         document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i].checked = false; 
        }          
         document.getElementById("name").value = this.cells[0].innerHTML;
         document.getElementById("lname").value = this.cells[1].innerHTML;
         document.getElementById("years").value = this.cells[2].innerHTML;
         document.getElementById("g_" + this.cells[3].innerHTML.trim().toLowerCase()).checked = true;
         var item_1 = this.cells[4].innerHTML.trim().toLowerCase();
         var item_2 = this.cells[5].innerHTML.trim().toLowerCase();

         item_1 != '' ? document.getElementById("m_" + item_1).checked = true : '';
         item_2 != '' ? document.getElementById("m_" + item_2).checked = true : '';
         /*Code for loading img*/
         document.getElementById("photo").value = this.cells[26].innerHTML;
            };  
        }
```

Comment: Set the `.src` attribute not the `.value` attribute (images don't have a value attribute at all).

Comment: Yeah!!! That's the answer!!!